# How can I keep display time on the timeline view?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

In the `timeline` view, time is displayed for 17 days or less, but
The time will be hidden when it is over 18 days.

```
views: {

//This is ok.
    custom17days: { 
      type: 'timeline',
        visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
            return {
                start: currentDate,
                end: currentDate.clone().add(17, 'days') 
            };
        }
    },

//*** time display disappears! why?
    custom18days: { 
      type: 'timeline',
        visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
            return {
                start: currentDate,
                end: currentDate.clone().add(18, 'days') 
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/nextageot/pen/JVLXMo?editors=0010

Do you know how to always display time regardless of the number of days?

Comment: Here is Sample code. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nextageot/pen/JVLXMo?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

it will try to guess, but if you specify an explicit [displayEventTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventTime) as `true`, it will always show the time.

Comment: I tried `displayEventTime: true` but the result was the same.
Also, [displayEventTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventTime) says **For timeline views, it depends on the duration.** I would like to make a request. Thank you.